# unable to pass wget a variable with quotes inside the variable

Tags: linux, bash, variables, wget, quotes

I am trying to script a wget command to download a web page and all it's attachments and jpegs etc.

When I enter the script by hand, it works, but I need to run this over 35000 times to archive an old web site which is outside of my control (international company politics, but I'm the owner of the data).

My problem has been in variablising the session parameters.

My script so far is as follows:

```
cnt=35209
# initialise the headers
general_settings='-4 -P xyz --restrict-file-names=windows -nc --limit-rate=250k'
html_page_specific='--convert-links --html-extension'
proxy='--proxy-user=xxxxxx --proxy-password=yyyyyyy' 
session="--header=\'Host: mywebsite.com:9090\' --header=\'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0\'"
address=http://mywebsite.com:9090/browse/item-$cnt

echo $general_settings $proxy $session $cookie $address
echo
echo
echo Getting item-$cnt...

#while [ $cnt -gt 0 ]
#do
#  # get the page
  wget --debug $general_settings $html_page_specific $proxy $session $cookie $address

  # now get the attachments, pdf, txt, jpg, gif, sql, etc...
#  wget -A.pdf  $general_settings -r $proxy $session $cookie $address
#  wget -A.txt  $general_settings -r $proxy $session $cookie $address
#  wget -A.jpg  $general_settings -r $proxy $session $cookie $address
#  wget -A.gif  $general_settings -r $proxy $session $cookie $address
#  wget -A.sql  $general_settings -r $proxy $session $cookie $address
#  wget -A.doc  $general_settings -r $proxy $session $cookie $address
#  wget -A.docx $general_settings -r $proxy $session $cookie $address
#  wget -A.xls  $general_settings -r $proxy $session $cookie $address
#  wget -A.xlsm $general_settings -r $proxy $session $cookie $address
#  wget -A.xlsx $general_settings -r $proxy $session $cookie $address
#  wget -A.xml  $general_settings -r $proxy $session $cookie $address
#  wget -A.ppt  $general_settings -r $proxy $session $cookie $address
#  wget -A.pptx $general_settings -r $proxy $session $cookie $address
#  wget -A.png  $general_settings -r $proxy $session $cookie $address
#  wget -A.ps   $general_settings -r $proxy $session $cookie $address
#  wget -A.mdb  $general_settings -r $proxy $session $cookie $address
#  ((cnt=cnt-1))
#
#done
```

but when I run the script, I get the following output

```
Getting item-35209...
Setting --inet4-only (inet4only) to 1
Setting --directory-prefix (dirprefix) to xyz
Setting --restrict-file-names (restrictfilenames) to windows
Setting --no (noclobber) to 1
Setting --limit-rate (limitrate) to 250k
Setting --convert-links (convertlinks) to 1
Setting --html-extension (htmlextension) to 1
Setting --proxy-user (proxyuser) to xxxxx
Setting --proxy-password (proxypassword) to yyyyy
Setting --header (header) to \'Host:
Setting --header (header) to 'Cookie:
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.11.4 Red Hat modified on linux-gnu.
```

As you can see, the Host and Cookie sections are not being properly formatted, resulting in the wget command failing to log in and extract the data.

I've been reading the bash man pages, googling, and have tried several related suggestions from SO, but I'm still unable to get the command to execute.

Anyone out there going to be nice enough to show me the correct way to quote quotes in veriables?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quotes inside of quoted strings or variables are ordinary characters, not quoting characters. There's no way to change that. Use an array instead:

```
A=(a b 'c d' 'e f')
cmd "${A[@]}"
```

calls `cmd` with four arguments `a`, `b`, `c d`, and `e f`.

(You could achieve a similar effect with `eval`, but that's a lot more error prone. In your case, using arrays is much more convenient.)

Comment: Uwe, 
Sorry to be dumb about this, but I don't see how this will make any difference, as my strings contain quotes, i.e.
"--header=\'Host: mywebsite.com:9090\'

Could you expand on how I would enter the variable value in the array so that the quotes would be read properly by Bash?

Comment: Or is the format that I'm using correct, and that by using the array, Bash will start to interpret them correctly?

Comment: Define `session=(--header='Host: mywebsite.com:9090' --header='User-Agent: ... Firefox/20.0')` and then use `"${session[@]}"` instead of `$session`. The other variables must be modified analogously.

Comment: Thanks, perfect.  Now I need to go research how the arrays work so that I actually understand what this is doing.  Much appreciated for the answer and example.

Answer (score -2):

```
session="--header=Host: mywebsite.com:9090 --header=User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0"
```

use this,

Comment: If you do this, then `wget` is either called with separate arguments `--header=Host:`, `mywebsite.com:9090`, `--header=User-Agent:`, `Mozilla/5.0`, etc. (if one uses `$session`), or with one single argument `--header=Host: ... Firefox/20.0` (if one uses `"$session"`). Neither of these does the intended thing, i.e., calling with two arguments `--header=Host: mywebsite.com:9090` and `--header=User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 ... Firefox/20.0`.

Comment: the comment above is correct.  This is exactly what I see in the output when I tried this prior to asking the question on SO.